# Is $T(X)$ a Banach space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a normed space and $T \colon X\to Y$ be a linear transformation. Then is $T(X)$ a Banach space? How do I prove this? I'm asking this since I saw a post saying this is true some hours ago (I don't remember the reference though, maybe it was on some forum and I believe the statement is false).

EDIT:

Let $T:V\to W$ is a bounded bijective operator where $V$ is a Banach space and $W$ is a normed space. Then, is $T(V)$ a Banach space?

Comment: The range of a bounded linear transformation need not be closed (see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080937/check-proof-about-range-of-bounded-linear-operator), e.g.). It's false.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you!

Comment: @DavidMitra Hmm.. i'm curious what condition should $T$ have to make $T(X)$ complete. What if $T$ is a bounded bijection? I'm really curious about it so I just edited my post.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Oops.. edited :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Let $T:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ be defined by $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)=\left(x_1,\frac12x_2,\frac13x_3,\ldots\right)$.  Then $T$ is injective and bounded, but its range is not closed.  Let $X=\ell^2$ and $Y=T(\ell^2)$ to get a counterexample for your question with $T$ being a bounded bijection from a Banach space to a normed space.

For your more general question in a comment, "I'm curious what condition should $T$ have to make $T(X)$ complete," in the context of $Y$ being a Banach space, see [When is the image of a linear operator closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26071/)

Comment: Thank you so much :) especially for the link